# How to update context variable in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Class extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        data:"NULL"
    };
}

setData(value) {
    this.setState({ data:value})
 }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.data}</div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.setData("Say Hi!")}>
                Say Hi!
            </button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.setData("Say Hello!")}>
                Say Hello!
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Now i want to maintain this state using Context API(global state).
MyContext Class:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ClassContext = React.ClassContext();

const ClassProvider = (props) => {
const [data, setData] = useState("NULL");

return (
    <ClassContext.Provider
        value={{
            data,
            setData,
        }}>
        {props.children}
    </ClassContext.Provider>
)
}

export { ClassContext, ClassProvider };
```

We can update state variable inside function in the first code snippet. But how to do the same update with context api?

Comment: Can you share a detailed code?

Comment: I have updated the code with details.

Comment: have you created context ?

Comment: Does this answers your question https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @SaifulIslamNiloy You can check how can use 

https://devsmitra.medium.com/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-2968a5cf5c83

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Comment: @RahulSharma I have included my context class here.

Comment: What isn't working? Can you clarify if there is any issue? If you are simply looking to implement and use the React Context API then I suggest you familiarize yourself with the docs Pulsara linked, SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: There are *many* ways to pass data to an outer scope. One of the easiest is to pass a function into your component that updates values in the calling component. But take a look at react-redux for a more advanced way to manage state and update it. And you probably don't mean `context` as that's a more advanced topic in React.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example

```
import React, { useState, createContext, Component } from "react";

const ClassContext = createContext();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ClassProvider>
      <Class />
    </ClassProvider>
  );
}

function ClassProvider(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("NULL");
  return (
    <ClassContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      {props.children}
    </ClassContext.Provider>
  );
}

class Class extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data, setData } = this.context;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{data}</div>
        <button onClick={() => setData("Say Hi!")}>Say Hi!</button>
        <button onClick={() => setData("Say Hello!")}>Say Hello!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Class.contextType = ClassContext;
```

[CSB example](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-dawn-dv3p4?file=/src/App.js) - I might delete CSB example at some point.

Alternatively you can also consume data and setData in class as

```
class Class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ClassContext.Consumer>
        {({ data, setData }) => (
          <div>
            <div>{data}</div>
            <button onClick={() => setData("Say Hi!")}>Say Hi!</button>
            <button onClick={() => setData("Say Hello!")}>Say Hello!</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </ClassContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above example you dont need to assign contextType property to class